# Dynamic "Terminal" Style Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I am trying to create a text box that is styled like a terminal window, On the bottom where you would usually type, right above that I would like some words that if you click on a word it would then print a specific paragraph into the "Terminal" Window.

I am using this for a personal website about coding. I would like to be able to click on the bar below on the "About" button and have it print an "About Coding" paragraph one letter at a time, kinda like you see in old 90s movies.

I need a place to start, maybe what the box should be coded in and or what that kind of thing is called. I cant for the life of me remember.

scoured the internet trying to find something similar and didnt come up with anything.

None to show yet.

Comment: The typing effect would be called typewriter or typing effect. Here are some examples:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/
https://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can approach this project. It is all based on what your end goal is (not just for the `Terminal` window page, but for the whole website in general). If this is something really small that doesn’t need for any data to persist (like having users, posts and etc) - you can go as simple as plain Javascript + HTML. You can also get really fancy with it and pick a front-end framework like Vue.js, React.js, Angular.js and etc. There are many different tools that you can use (here is a list from GitHub: https://github.com/collections/front-end-javascript-frameworks).

However, if we are looking to specifically tackle the task at hand - I would recommend using plain old Javascript with HTML.

Here is a small start for you, hope it helps (please see / run the snippet).

```js
function kenobi() {
        const customContent = document.createElement('div');
        customContent.innerHTML = 'Hello there, General Kenobi!';
        customContent.id = 'custom-content';

        const referenceNode = document.querySelector('#you-are-a-bold-one');
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(customContent, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
```

```css
.terminal {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#custom-content {
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
    border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
    letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
    animation:
        typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
        blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: grey; }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Terminal Window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="terminal">
        <div>Last login: Sun May 19 23:31:48 on ttys000</div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="intro" id="you-are-a-bold-one">~ $&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="about-button" onclick="kenobi()">About</button>
  </body>
</html>
```